# Как правильно добавить больше одной подписки в приложение?

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchases, android-billing

У меня в приложении уже есть рабочая подписка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я ее вызываю:

```
fun startSubscription(activity: Activity) {
        val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(arrayListOf(SUBSCRIPTION_ID))
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).build()
        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
            when (billingResult.responseCode) {
                BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK -> {
                    if (skuDetailsList.orEmpty().isNotEmpty()) {
                        skuDetailsList!!.forEach {
                            val purchaseParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(it).build()
                            billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, purchaseParams)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Я пробовал поменять первую строку вот так:

```
val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(arrayListOf(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_YEAR_ID))
                .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS).build()
```

Но у меня открывалось два диалога поверх друг друга.
Вопрос в следующем можно ли как-то показывать обе подписки на гугл форме, или надо создавать две разных кнопки для двух разных подписок?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать? Дать юзеру возможность в одно нажатие оформить 2 подписки? Такое сделать нельзя. Наверное, вам надо 2 разные кнопки, хотя и не точно. Ибо не очень понятна ваша задача.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Нет, подписку оформить можно только одну, вопрос в том можно ли предоставить выбор прям на гугловском окне, или надо делать две кнопки которые открывают тот или иной вариант?!

Comment: Надо 2 кнопки. Влиять на гугловый иинтерфейс невозможно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо большое за ответ